# How can I obfuscate using "control flow flattening" at android native lib?

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface, obfuscation

How can I obfuscate using "control flow flattening" at android native lib?

build tool is Cmake.

when I saw IDA pseudocode view, I could see originally code. could I hide original

code using something like control flow flattening?

Comment: when I saw IDA pseudocode view, I could see originally code.
could I hide original code using something like control flow flattening?

Comment: To improve your question, please edit it accordingly. Do not use [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to add major information. Consider comments to be temporary, not persistent information.